# Download lager object from local server instead of the global internet

Tags: javascript, server, iot

The Store web app requires downloading objects (each of which is 50 MB) from the internet and it takes a lot of time to download.

In order to solve this I am thinking to pre-download these objects in some local server. And when the user uses this web App. The web app downloads these object from the local server instead of the internet (All this happening in the same network).

So, the questions are,
1- Is this feasible?
2- Is there any library available to do this?
3- Is there any alternative available?
4- Should I use Iot device as a local sever?